# C++ File Reading Library - ANSI and Unicode

Tags: c++, unicode, file-io

I've read a few answers on here about reading Unicode files etc and most people point to UTF8-CPP or iconv.

None of the libraries that I found work for both ANSI and Unicode files, ideally I want one function which I pass a filename to and it will return the contents of that file and it won't matter what the encoding is, or is that not possible?

If so any suggestions how I would go about it?

Comment: The holy grail of 100% guaranteed auto-detecting the file encoding is not possible. There are algorithms to guess but they are not 100% reliable.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that is a binary read isn't ? All other forms are a matter of interpretation and then the exact encoding etc becomes important.

While due to BOM, unicode can be autodetected in some cases, it's not always there, and a failed detection mechanism then equals a broken program. I assume that is the reason why most people refrain from it.

Answer (score 0):

UTF8-CPP can detecte UTF8 (utf8::is_valid and utf8::find_invalid) and do conversion (utf8::utf16to8) if you're using widestring. It works great, what's the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of techniques:

In general, most Unicode files start with the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Which means if the file starts with `0xfffe` or `0xfeff` you *may* assume that it's Unicode. Not many people use UTF-32 AFAIK but you can still use the BOM method to guess (refer to Wiki page).

If it's a UTF-8 file, you can use UTF8-CPP to convert it UTF-16 (`wstring`). If it's a UTF-16 file, it can be difficult to read using the standard library. For taht, you can refer to my blog post:

http://cfc.kizzx2.com/index.php/reading-a-unicode-utf16-file-in-windows-c/

For UTF-32 -- I don't know if anyone uses it, so I have no experience :P